# Как размыть края изображения средствами ffmpeg, go или cli?

Tags: изображения, golang, ffmpeg, обработка-изображений

Есть входящие изображения разного размера и разрешения. Необходимо размыть их края с переходом в прозрачность и наложить на видео посредством ffmpeg.

Я так понимаю, что средствами ffmpeg это будет сделать крайне затруднительно(хоть и желательно), поэтому подскажите какие-то инструменты для этой задачи, желательно с библиотеками на go, либо с cli.

Пока единственное, что смог реализовать - это использование 2х изображений. Одно размывается полностью, а второе накладывается сверху с обрезкой. Но этот метод не подходит, т.к. сильно видно края обрезанного изображения, нужно чтобы переход был плавным.

[image: Исходное изображение]

[image: Результат]